# How do I get the skype panel icon back?

Tags: skype, notification-area

i m a less that 10 hours user of ubuntu 10.10. i have installed skype.the first time i installed it there was a green icon on the panel with my status but i closed it by wrong.any idea how to return it?thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go to to panel --> notification area.

Answer (score 1):

To access skype,

- Goto Applications>>Internet>>Skype

Comment: thanks for your answer but i was not looking for that.i was looking for my status and i found it (add to panel-->notification area).thanks anyway

Comment: Alright :) you are welcome..

Comment: @kostas Add that as a seperate answer and then mark it accepted so the next person can benefit!